# Cron Job targeting non-default AppEngine version

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

I'm trying to get my Cron job to target a different version in AppEngine.  Using [this link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron#Cron_and_App_Versions) I can see that

> The target string is prepended to your app's hostname. It is usually
>   the name of a module. The cron job will be routed to the default
>   version of the named module. Note that if the default version of the
>   module changes, the job will run in the new default version.

Here is my cron

> ```
> <cron>
>     <url>/cron/prices</url>
>     <description>Updates every 30 seconds</description>
>     <schedule>every 30 seconds</schedule>
>     <target>dev</target>
> </cron>
> ```

My appengine-web.xml portion

> ```
> <application>project</application>
> <version>dev</version>
> <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
> ```

However, I also have a default version (called "1") and everytime I check the logs, cron/prices is running against version 1 instead of dev.  I have also tried dev-dot-project and dev-project but they don't seem to work.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot...

The correct target should be "dev", the problem I was having was with Android Studio/Gradle.  I was using 'gradle appengineUpdateCron' while forgetting to update the classes with 'gradle appengineUpdateAll' causing it to error out.